# Strange traffic from an external domain in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-news

I'm a Google News publisher and I use Google Analytics to track my traffic.

Today I see hits to an external URL (Googlee News) in my stats

[image: Real time]

I have no clue where is this coming from. Any idea?

Comment: If you segment the active page by device and/or browser, does it show primarily mobile activity?

Comment: @vinoaj yes it does

Comment: OK, so my theory is that your articles are being accessed via an app (e.g. Google News app, Google Search app, etc.) and WebView is used to show the articles. At this point, Google uses news.google.com to be the "wrapper" for the WebView OR it is picking up a cached version from news.google.com. In either case your GA code fires and reports on the full URL being used to read your article.